# R Combine columns in one dataframe with another while removing old columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a main data frame where i have created new columns based on old columns

I created subsets of the main data frame for these columns initially and performed some transformations and now wish to merge the columns back removing the old columns in the process

The old columns in the main data frame are called `rev_quest_7` and `rev_quest_5` and contain 7 columns and five columns respectively

The new columns I created from the previous columns are called `updated_7` and `updated_5` and contain the same amount of columns and data

All four are data frames.

```
mydf_calc <- mydf%>% 
  select(everything(), -rev_quest_7, -rev_quest_5) %>% 
  bind_cols(updated_7, updated_5)
```

In the end I wish to merge the data frames `updated_7` and `updated_5` main frames `rev_quest_7`, `rev_quest_5` from the main data frame creating a new data frame called `mydf_calc`. All four  five items in this question are data frames

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are `rev_quest_7` and `rev_quest_5` data frames or are they just collections of column names or numbers from `mydf`? Your question seems to suggest the latter first and then the former last.

Comment: Hi @aichao  all four items are data frames. In essence i took a subset of columns, did some work on them and created the 2 new data frames out of it. The old features in the main data set as represented by the original sub data frames are now redundant. So i basically want to remove the columns that are in `mydf` which exist in the original data frames. I could code it manually but there are quite a few columns in the sub data frames so i was hoping to be able to just use the previous work for an elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `select_` to programmatically specify the columns to remove using the column names from data frames `rev_quest_7` and `rev_quest_5`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf_calc <- mydf %>% select_(.dots=paste0("-",unique(c(colnames(rev_quest_7),colnames(rev_quest_5))))) %>%
                      bind_cols(update_7,update_5)
```

I will illustrate with a simple example where `rev_quest_7` and `rev_quest_5` only have `2` columns from `mydf`, but that should not matter:

```
mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4,c=3:5,d=4:6,e=5:7)
##  a b c d e
##1 1 2 3 4 5
##2 2 3 4 5 6
##3 3 4 5 6 7
## rev_quest_7 extracts columns "a" and "c"
rev_quest_7 <- mydf[,c(1,3)]
## rev_quest_5 extracts columns "b" and "d"
rev_quest_5 <- mydf[,c(2,4)]
## update_7 and update_5 operates on rev_quest_7 and rev_quest_5, respectively
update_7 <- 2 * rev_quest_7
##  a  c
##1 2  6
##2 4  8
##3 6 10
update_5 <- 3 * rev_quest_5
##   b  d
##1  6 12
##2  9 15
##3 12 18

mydf_calc <- mydf %>% select_(.dots=paste0("-",unique(c(colnames(rev_quest_7),colnames(rev_quest_5))))) %>%
                      bind_cols(update_7,update_5)
##  e a  c  b  d
##1 5 2  6  6 12
##2 6 4  8  9 15
##3 7 6 10 12 18
```

Comment: Gosh, that is very clever. Thank you so much